# Property or method "posts" is not defined in the instance in Windows 7

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, nuxt.js

I made a strange problem. I have a code works perfectly in MacOS, but in **Windows 7**, it goes error: TypeError: **Property or method "posts" is not defined in the instance**.
Please take a look my code.

```
<template>
  <div class="row flex">
    <div class="col-md-2 left_nav">
      <leftnav/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 home_feed">
      <post-detail :posts="posts"></post-detail>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 flex">
      <explorecol/>
    </div>
    <chatcol/>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  import leftnav from '~/components/newsfeed/Nav.vue'
  import chatcol from '~/components/Chat_Col.vue'
  import explorecol from '~/components/feeds/Explore_Col.vue'
  import Item from '~/components/feeds/Post.vue'
  export default {
    async asyncData ({ route }) {
      let { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/feeds/' + route.params.id + '/')
      return {
        posts: data
      }
    },
    components: {
      leftnav,
      chatcol,
      explorecol,
      'post-detail': Item
    }
  }
</script>
```

I've made errors since I've installed package called: [Vue Router Module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-module). I use NuxtJS.

Comment: I think it is not Windows 7, but browser related problem. Are you using Internet Explorer 11?

Comment: Firefox get error too. But in Mac. Both of Safari and Chrome works normally. :(

Comment: Found it: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3. Fixed